# T-SQL concatenate VarChar with comma

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I'm new to SQL.  I have this working SQL function, but I would like to join the results with a comma in a way that leaves no extraneous commas if the result is empty.  I had a play with COALESCE but I couldn't get it to work.  Any clues or help would be great.

In Python I would do this:

```
'abcdef'.join(', ')
```

Here is the SQL function now:

```
USE [Broadcast]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[MapConsumerAdvice]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 14:49:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MapConsumerAdvice] 
(
    @A as Int,
    @B as Int,
    @C as Int,
    @D as Int,
    @E as Int,
    @F as Int,
    @G as Int,
    @H as Int
)
RETURNS VarChar(20)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Result as VarChar(999)

    SET @Result = ''

    IF (@A > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'a'
    IF (@B > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'd'
    IF (@C > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'h'
    IF (@D > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'l'
    IF (@E > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'm'
    IF (@F > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'n'
    IF (@G > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 's'
    IF (@H > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'v'

    Return @Result

END
```

Comment: Presumably this should be tagged SQL Server. Please add this tag (or a different one if you're using a different RDBMS). Also, I'd strongly advise *against* doing this. SQL Server *has* a data type that is perfectly suited to storing multiple values. It's called a table. If you use the types that are provided, you'll tend to find that queries are easier to write and more likely to perform well.

Comment: You need to remove the leading comma in the result?

Comment: @techdo yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RETURN SUBSTRING(@Result, 2, LEN(@Result))
```

or

```
RETURN RIGHT(@Result, LEN(@Result)-1)
```

instead of `Return @Result`

Answer (score 0):

add below code at end of function,

```
RETURN REPLACE(@result,',,',',')
```

Comment: If i am not wrong..i presume if any of parameter to function is passed '' (empty space) then u need to add above code..as it may end in ur result as a,bc,,f

Comment: No, the solution I marked seems to work fine with empty space.  Thank you for your suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

You do need to check if anything was assigned.

```
USE [Broadcast]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[MapConsumerAdvice]    Script Date: 04/24/2013 14:49:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MapConsumerAdvice] 
(
    @A as Int,
    @B as Int,
    @C as Int,
    @D as Int,
    @E as Int,
    @F as Int,
    @G as Int,
    @H as Int
)
RETURNS VarChar(20)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Result as VarChar(999)

SET @Result = ''

IF (@A > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'a'
IF (@B > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'd'
IF (@C > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'h'
IF (@D > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'l'
IF (@E > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'm'
IF (@F > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'n'
IF (@G > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 's'
IF (@H > 0) SET @Result = @Result + ',' + 'v'

IF PATINDEX(',%', @Result) > 1 Set @Result = SUBSTRING(@Result, 2, LEN(@Result));

Return @Result

END
```